# woocommerce order status stock reduction stop

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, woocommerce, product

I am using woocommerce I take payment by bacs and the order comes in as on hold I am using a piece of code whch does not reduce the stock when the order comes in and this works

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_can_reduce_order_stock', 'wcs_do_not_reduce_onhold_stock', 10, 2 );
function wcs_do_not_reduce_onhold_stock( $reduce_stock, $order ) {
    if ( $order->has_status( 'on-hold', 'processing' ) && $order->get_payment_method() == 'bacs' ) {
        $reduce_stock = false;
    }
    return $reduce_stock;
}
```

and within the order when the status is changed to eg processing, completed, pending payment the stock is reduced, I would like to stop this please how would I go about it

Comment: How do you call this function? With a hook?

Comment: hey Mr Jo with a filter add_filter                ( 'woocommerce_can_reduce_order_stock', 'wcs_do_not_reduce_onhold_stock', 10, 2 );

Comment: Please edit your original question and add the required details!

Comment: hey Mr. Jo I have now :)

Comment: Can you please try to debug log the value returned from the function `$order->get_payment_method()` to confirm `bacs` is the correct value? Also, I would suggest adding the missing order status values to the function `has_status()` since currently it only checks for `on-hold` and `processing`.

Comment: hey Mr.Jo that is not the issue, in admin in the order when eg processing status is set the stock reduces, I do not want that, how would I g about stopping the stock reduction for processing status in admin

Comment: I'm currently debugging your own function with you to find the problem. This is the way I would go for it to check if your function also get even called when changing the status from the admin page. So debugging is not an issue but a solution for a coding problem.